# Unix command to search file1 id in another file2 and write result to a file3

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I have to read ids from one file and search it in second xml file, if found write that entire line to third file. file1 is 111 MB, file2 is 40 GB

File1.xml

```
id1
id2
id5
```

File2.xml

```
<employees>
<employee><id>id1</id><name>test1</name></employee>
<employee><id>id2</id><name>test2</name></employee>
<employee><id>id3</id><name>test3</name></employee>
<employee><id>id4</id><name>test4</name></employee>
<employee><id>id5</id><name>test5</name></employee>
<employee><id>id6</id><name>test6</name></employee>
</employees>
```

File3.xml : result

```
<employee><id>id1</id><name>test1</name></employee>
<employee><id>id2</id><name>test2</name></employee>
<employee><id>id5</id><name>test5</name></employee>
```

i tried it with grep

```
grep -i -f file1.xml file2.xml >> file3.xml
```

but its giving memory exhausted error.

Another way i tried it with loop and awk command.

```
#while read -r id;do
#awk  -v pat="$id" '$0~pat' file2.xml  >> file3.xml
#done < file1.xml
```

its also taking too much time.
What could be the best optimal solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in any awk version:

```sh
awk 'FNR == NR {
   seen["<id>" $1 "</id>"]
   next
}
match($0, /<id>[^<]*<\/id>/) && substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) in seen
' file1 file2

<employee><id>id1</id><name>test1</name></employee>
<employee><id>id2</id><name>test2</name></employee>
<employee><id>id5</id><name>test5</name></employee>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its superfast. Took 30 min for entire run.

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v FPAT='<id>[^<]*</id>' '
FNR==NR{
  arr["<id>"$0"</id>"]
  next
}
($1 in arr)
' file1.xml file2.xml
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v FPAT='<id>[^<]*</id>' '   ##Starting awk program and setting FPAT to <id>[^<]*<\\/id>
FNR==NR{                         ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when file1.xml is being read.
  arr["<id>"$0"</id>"]           ##Creating an array arr which has index of <id> $0 </id> here.
  next                           ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in arr)                      ##Checking condition if $1 is present in arr then print that line.
' file1.xml file2.xml            ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: It is a cool idea to use `FPAT`.

Comment: No escaping needed, just `FPAT='<id>[^<]*</id>'` would work fine